# Invalid UDID format iPhone X , Xs (24 characters with dash)

Tags: ios, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I get a UDID from client-side like as bellow (24 characters with dash).

Formatted is 00000000-0000000000000000 (24 characters plus a dash).

When I add this UDID to the developer account, I get an error (invalid UDID). I have also checked the following post. Unfortunately, it didn't help me find any solutions.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108848

Comment: Just open itunes.. click serial number.. until you see UUID.. Then use that. Otherwise let Xcode add the device for you.